# Is it possible to disable the Touchscreen backlight rate limit?

Tags: touchscreen

Is it possible to disable the Touchscreen backlight rate limit?

I am developing an embedded application, and would like to fade the backlight smoothly on and off.

But the rate limit of no more than two backlight brightness changes per second in the firmware prevents fades.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think this has been addressed in user linusg's `rpi-backlight` Python library on Github [here](https://github.com/linusg/rpi-backlight). They've embedded a short video clip on that page which shows the effect they've achieved - looks like smooth fading to me.

They included a short example on running the code. I think the relevant line is `bl.ets_brightness(20, smooth=True, duration=3)`:

```
>>> import rpi_backlight as bl
>>> bl.set_brightness(255)
>>> bl.set_brightness(20, smooth=True, duration=3)
>>> bl.get_max_brightness()
255
>>> bl.get_actual_brightness()
20
>>> bl.get_power()
True
>>> bl.set_power(False)
```